# Massive Memory Leaks?

Tags: windows-7, macos, vmware-fusion, memory-leaks

I seem to have huge memory leaks, which are confusing me.

I'm running fusion 3.1 / Windows 7 on Snow Leopard. It's a clean install with all upgrades applied. I've given fusion 8GB on a 14GB machine.

I've installed VS2008 & Eclipse in Windows 7. Nothing unusual.

Inside Task Manager in Windows 7, my memory footprint stays reasonable, at <2GB. But in OSX, Activity Monitor shows the footprint of vmware-vmx to be much larger. It starts at 2 GB, which seems fine, but whenever I'm actually doing anything in Windows, vmware-vmx's footprint grows at a few MB per second. After 20 mins or so it's using ~10GB and everything grinds to a halt. Throughout this, Task Manager still says I'm only using 2GB. And whatever I do in windows seems to increase vmware-vmx's memory footprint. Even closing down an application seems to make it go up.

So is this par for the course in fusion? I was previously using parallels 3 / Vista under Leopard, and it worked fine. I'd assumed my new fusion config would work better, but this makes it completely unusable. (And apparently I can't even ask tech support unless I buy a support package...)

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you share your problem with the VMWare SUpport? They might be interested in this behavior.

Comment: Try to reduce Windows memory to 4GB and see what happens. 10GB might still be the allowed 8 plus some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about OSX, but in Windows I use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the memory usage of suspect applications.  I had one that kept claiming memory and not releasing it, which made the memory graph look like a continuous stairway.  It won't tell you why the memory is leaking, but it will tell you what app is leaking it.  Process Monitor is much more informative than Task Manager.