# Massive Memory Leaks?

Tags: vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Massive Memory Leaks?](https://superuser.com/questions/94419/massive-memory-leaks)

Hi,

I seem to have huge memory leaks, which are confusing me.

I'm running fusion 3.1 / Windows 7 on Snow Leopard. It's a clean install with all upgrades applied. I've given fusion 8GB on a 14GB machine.

I've installed VS2008 & Eclipse in Windows 7. Nothing unusual.

Inside Task Manager in Windows 7, my memory footprint stays reasonable, at <2GB. But in OSX, Activity Monitor shows the footprint of vmware-vmx to be much larger. It starts at 2 GB, which seems fine, but whenever I'm actually doing anything in Windows, vmware-vmx's footprint grows at a few MB per second. After 20 mins or so it's using ~10GB and everything grinds to a halt. Throughout this, Task Manager still says I'm only using 2GB. And whatever I do in windows seems to increase vmware-vmx's memory footprint. Even closing down an application seems to make it go up.

So is this par for the course in fusion? I was previously using parallels 3 / Vista under Leopard, and it worked fine. I'd assumed my new fusion config would work better, but this makes it completely unusable. (And apparently I can't even ask tech support unless I buy a support package...)

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate question from the same user: http://superuser.com/questions/94419/massive-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other virtual machines running that experience similar problems?

It might be a problem with the program's 'memory ballooning' driver (vmmemctl driver) you could try to fix it by manually replacing it. Honestly, the best thing to do might be to uninstall VMware, reinstall it, and not patch it all the way up and see if that works. You could then test to see if a patch causes a problem.